# Background colors on Luhn Algorithm - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to learn to become a web developer and have a task where I need to use luhn algorithm to check credit cards are valid. If they are valid the box goes green, if they are not the box goes red. I’ve found the below javascript on GitHub that looks to do what I need, but I am unsure on how to add the code to make the boxes change colour. I believe I need an if/ else statement but I’m not sure how to implement it. I was thinking something like this as the code for the color change:

`document.getElementById(‘cardInput’).style.backgroundColor = “green”;`

Here is my html:

```
     <form name="form1" action="#">
       <ul>
         <li>Name:<input id="nameInput" onkeyup="letterscheck(this)" type='text' name='name' placeholder="Enter Your Name"/></li>
         <li>Email:<input id="emailInput" onkeyup="emailcheck(this)" type='text' name='email'placeholder="Enter Your Email"/></li>
         <li>Card:<input id="cardInput" onkeyup="cardnumber(this)" type='text' name='card' placeholder="Enter a Proxy Credit Card Number."/></li>
         <li class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  /></li>
       </ul>
     </form>
   </div>
```

Here is the JS i found on GitHub:

```
function cardnumber(value) {
if (/[^0-9-\s]+/.test(value))
return false;
let nCheck = 0, bEven = false;
value = value.replace(/\D/g, “”);
for (var n = value.length - 1; n >= 0; n–) {
var cDigit = value.charAt(n),
nDigit = parseInt(cDigit, 10);
if (bEven && (nDigit *= 2) > 9) nDigit -= 9;
nCheck += nDigit;
bEven = !bEven;
}
return (nCheck % 10) == 0;
}
```

My JS for the other 2 fields

```
 function letterscheck(inputtxt)
  {
    var namechecker = /^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[\s.]+[a-zA-Z]+)*$/;
    if(inputtxt.value.match(namechecker))
          {
        document.getElementById('nameInput').style.backgroundColor = "green";
        return true;
          }
        else
          {
          document.getElementById('nameInput').style.backgroundColor = "red";;
          return false;
          }
  }


  function emailcheck(inputtxt)
    {
      var emailchecker = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      if(inputtxt.value.match(emailchecker))
            {
          document.getElementById('emailInput').style.backgroundColor = "green";
          return true;
            }
          else
            {
            document.getElementById('emailInput').style.backgroundColor = "red";
            return false;
            }
    }
```

Hopefully, this is a really easy one for you all! Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Which box should we color, the `li` or `input`. Is `cardnumber()` the function that returns the `boolean` value for the right card number?

Comment: What you've tried so far

Comment: Hi, I've edited my original post to add in the full task. It must have a Name field, an email field and a card field using luhn validation. The other 2 boxes function correctly, the box you type in goes red or green depending on the input. I need the Card: box to do the same but i just don't have the knowledge to know how to implement it.

Comment: Please add the source of the `cardnumber` function algorithm

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm contains several errors so I've searched and found on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310837/implementation-of-luhn-algorithm)

You can change the `background-color` conditionally. I've changed the `background-color` inside the `letterscheck` for `name` field. You can return `true` or `false` and do it in the `addEventListener` like in `email` field.

```js
const nameInput = document.querySelector("#nameInput")
const emailInput = document.querySelector("#emailInput")
const cardNumberInput = document.querySelector("#cardInput")

function valid_credit_card(value) {
  if (/[^0-9-\s]+/.test(value)) return false;

  var nCheck = 0,
    nDigit = 0,
    bEven = false;
  value = value.replace(/\D/g, "");

  for (var n = value.length - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
    var cDigit = value.charAt(n),
      nDigit = parseInt(cDigit, 10);

    if (bEven) {
      if ((nDigit *= 2) > 9) nDigit -= 9;
    }

    nCheck += nDigit;
    bEven = !bEven;
  }

  return (nCheck % 10) == 0;
}


function letterscheck(inputtxt) {
  var namechecker = /^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[\s.]+[a-zA-Z]+)*$/;
  if (inputtxt.match(namechecker)) {
    nameInput.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else {
    nameInput.style.backgroundColor = "red";;
  }
}


function emailcheck(inputtxt) {
  var emailchecker = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return inputtxt.match(emailchecker);
}

nameInput.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  letterscheck(e.target.value);
})

emailInput.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  const isEmailValid = emailcheck(e.target.value)
  if (isEmailValid) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
})

cardNumberInput.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  const isCardValid = valid_credit_card(e.target.value);
  if (isCardValid) {
    cardNumberInput.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else {
    cardNumberInput.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
})
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

input {
  margin: .25rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" action="#">
  <ul>
    <li>Name:<input id="nameInput" type='text' name='name' placeholder="Enter Your Name" /></li>
    <li>Email:<input id="emailInput" type='text' name='email' placeholder="Enter Your Email" /></li>
    <li>Card:<input id="cardInput" type='text' name='card' placeholder="Enter a Proxy Credit Card Number." /></li>
    <li class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```